# Sqlalchemy "like" vs "=="

Tags: sqlalchemy

I inherited a system that has plenty of queries with "like" without "%" and I'm wondering if it just works as an equal operator under the hood.

Is "query.filter(User.name == 'John')" the same as "query.filter(User.name.like ('John'))"?

Will both the result/performance be the same?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pure DB question, it basically comes down to what's faster:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE Name = 'John';
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE Name LIKE 'John';
```

both will produce the same results but `LIKE` will be a bit slower because it will do pattern match (vs `==` which is the exact match). You probably won't notice much difference if you're working with a small table, but for big tables (e.g. mils of recs) it will be quite noticeable.